# How to store state in profiles?

Tags: asp.net

```
<profile>
          <properties>
              <add name="Name" allowAnonymous="true" />
              <add name="Age" allowAnonymous="true" type="System.Int16"/>
          </properties>
          <providers>
              <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"
                   connectionStringName="ProfileServices"
                   applicationName="/"
                   type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" />
          </providers>
    </profile>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      <add name="ProfileServices"
           connectionString="Data source=CHANDAN-PC;Database=testdb;integrated security=sspi;"
           />

  </connectionStrings>
```

I get the following error : The SSE Provider did not find the database file specified in the connection string. At the configured trust level (below High trust level), the SSE provider can not automatically create the database file.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What are you trying to accomplish, specifically? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. What results did you get? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting? (no, it's not self-evident, that's why I'm asking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [MSDN: ASP.Net State Management Overview](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/aspnethub/a/ASPNETH_ProfileState.htm)
- [Maintaining State With Profiles in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx)